# Как распарсить из json поле типа Serializable

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть класс:

```
public class Entity<T extends Serializable, E extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T data;
    private E error;

    public Entity() {
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public E getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(E error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

И есть другой класс:

```
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer num;

    public Client() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(Integer num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

Могу ли я как-то распарсить следующий json:

```
{"data": { "name": "none", "num": 12}, "error":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Десеарилизация происходит автоматически, все что вам нужно это распарсить json в джава pojo. 
Для этого вы можете использовать `gson` но я советую лучше `Jackson Mapper`, он очень простой в использовании и по примерам сможете легко разобраться как это сделать. 
Если вы хотите сделать это в Spring MVC, можете входящим параметром указать `(@RequestBody YourObject ojb)` но при этом сначала наконфижить джексон и он будет делать это автоматически.

Comment: Я понимаю что можно сделать так:  mapper.readValue(entity, Entity.class), а как можно сделать что-то вроде  mapper.readValue(entity, Entity<Client, Error>.class)?

Comment: @MaxArt думаю вам надо посмотреть в сторону TypeReference - http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html